# Modelagem Base de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Especificando as tabelas que estou com dúvida são, no meu caso, um trabalho de uma empresa para o colégio, as tabelas: Entrada e Diagnóstico, em que a entrada é quando alguém trás algum equipamento, e depois é feito o diagnóstico, porem o diagnóstico tem mais de 40 campos, então eu dividi eles em 5 tabelas por categorias. Queria perguntar se dividir um tabela em 5 por conter demasiados campos numa só tabela, estará a não seguir as regras de normalização?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não tem nada a ver com [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), nem para melhor, nem pra pior. A não ser que tenha requisitos ocultos na pergunta, não posso falar sobre o que não está escrito.

De uma maneira geral eu não faria essa separação a não ser que tenha um bom motivo. Sé vejo desvantagens, fica mais lento, complica a aplicação, facilita cometer mais erros. A vantagem de ser "mais organizado" é bastante questionável. Alguns dirão que está desorganizando, já que separar o que é uma coisa única, provavelmente, é algo pior.

Toda decisão que um programador toma deve ser baseada em justificativas realistas e critérios bem definidos, trazendo alguma vantagem real sem trazer desvantagens indesejáveis. Duvido que consiga dar uma boa justificativa para separar estes campos.

Comment: Separei para diferenciar as categorias, apenas isso, mas todas as categorias pertencem ao mesmo diagnóstico e as relações serão todas iguais. Eu estou acostumado a separar as coisas o máximo possível porque receio que possa interferir de algum modo no futuro. Mas obrigado @bigown , entendi o seu (e de outros) pontos de vista, o meu objetivo é perceber as bases com a opinião de terceiros para que consiga chegar "mais alto" :)

Comment: Não seria o caso de Tipo de Diagnóstico ? Mas difícil opinar sem ver o levantamento.

Answer (score 1):

Essa "separação" se baseou na definição de alguma das Formas Normais?! Se você conseguir justificar com base no enunciado de alguma FN ok (lembrando que elas são cumulativas).

Como o @Maniero comentou, se o projeto é pequeno e não tem pretensão de escalabilidade, não faz sentido a separação. Talvez a normalização só adicionaria complexidade desnecessária.

Entretanto, se você tem interesse e/ou necessidade de já fazer desde o inicio um projeto de banco de dados seguindo boas práticas, convém normalizar.

A normalização é um processo passo-a-passo. Não dá pra pular etapas.
Pesquise sobre as **Formas** **Normais** e aplique até, no mínimo, a **3FN**.